# MATLAB Graphing plots with axes

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I have been trying to Create a program with the GUI in MATLAB. When I try to plot information with AXES I can not figure out how to do it. I know about the function plot, but I need to be able to re-size and move the plot around in the figure so I can make room for the input uicontrol. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how axes() is not working for you?

Comment: Well To tell you the truth, I am confused on how it works. Is that function just for axes options? so you have to plot first then adjust the axes?

Comment: @ponger3d Yes axes is used to modify axis properties. See the examples in [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) on how to use it. You do not need to plot anything to adjust the axes. Have a look at [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) which might suit your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to tackle this problem. But the way I always choose to do so, is:

hold on:

```
plot(...), xlim([xmin xmax), ylim(ymin ymax])
```

This should set your bounds on the axis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab at hand right now, but try the following:

To set size of the plot axes inside the figure window use

```
set(gca,'Position',[left bottom width height])
```

see Mathworks' [site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) on axes properties